# How to create Hexagon in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiview

I want to make `UIView` which is originally rectangular to Hexagon shape to be used in my application.

Please help me something on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subclass UView and override `drawRect` to draw a hexagon like so:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{    
    float polySize = 60; // change this

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGAffineTransform t0 = CGContextGetCTM(context);
    t0 = CGAffineTransformInvert(t0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, t0);

    //Begin drawing setup
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGPoint center;

    //Start drawing polygon
    center = CGPointMake(160, 90.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y + polySize);
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        CGFloat x = polySize * sinf(i * 2.0 * M_PI / 6);
        CGFloat y = polySize * cosf(i * 2.0 * M_PI / 6);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x + x, center.y + y);
    }

    //Finish Drawing
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tested the code down there, but this doesn't exactly make a UIView with hexagonal frame, this "simply" draws a hexagon inside the frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of UIView and in it's `-(void)drawRect:` method draw a hexagon. Or Use UIImageView with image of hexagon